# EPPlus LoadFromDataTable Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, epplus

I am getting the weirdest error from EPPlus and wondering if anyone else has gotten this / found a workaround...

If I use the following code, everything works out great:

```
wks.Cells(2, 20).LoadFromDataTable(dtFXData, True)
```

But when I change it to this:

```
wks.Cells(2, 26).LoadFromDataTable(dtFXData, True)
```

I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException** - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Start cell Address must be less or equal to End cell address`

I am using EPPlus version 3.1.2.

Any thoughts / help???

Comment: As added info on the question, when I changed my EPPlus from Version 3.1.2 to 3.0, it now works again...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i solved it backing to version 3.0 of EPPLUS...
EPPlus 3.0.0.2
Jan 31, 2012, Stable

See end of this forum, please: https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/407120

Good Luck!